# Kubernetes, Running VPA with Recommendations Only and HPA

Tags: kubernetes

There are already a million questions and answers stating you cannot run a VPA+HPA at the same time in your cluster performing modifications, for obvious reasons.

However, my question is can you run a VPA in recommend only mode (`updateMode: "Off"`) with an active HPA? Seems like others have had this question but I haven't found a definitive answer to my question. I just want to be really safe before I just start turning things on and have some stuff break.

Others have asked here: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/3858

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I just took the plunge and deployed it. So far I'm not having any issues. So it appears to be safe to deploy a VPA+HPA both watching CPU and Memory but have the VPA set with `updateMode: "Off"`.

Comment: Wanted to see if this is still the case and you have seen no issues? I'm looking to the do the same to better understanding tuning across many clusters. Did you find it useful as well?

Comment: You can safely run both fine as long as only one is doing the update. Didn't really use it though, so probably not overly useful